# Fail to start graphic interface

Tags: boot, gui

I'm using Linux Mint 14 and have faced the following problem recently:

after removing and installing some of the software (torchat and LibreOffice to be exact) and rebooting I found myself not being able to log into my system.

first thing I noticed was simply a console line offering to enter my login and password, after that it greeted me with

```
bash: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt: No such file or directory
```

all my attempts to run **startx** resulted in nothing but a black screen with an active mouse arrow

briefly serfing the net I've found that installing mdm could be a possible solution, however, after I did that, I've started logging into this very black screen immediately, skipping any time in console, so had to remove it. None of any other methods found on the internet seem to work.

here's the log file for startx:

*first lots of built-in extensions are being initialized*

```
loading extension GLX
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
Warning: Compat map for group 2 redefined
Using new definition
Warning: Compat map for group 3 redefined
Using new definition
Warning: Compat map for group 4 redefined
Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

this report repeats 3 times and in the end I get:

```
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
xinit: unexpected signal 1
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions about working this mess out. Thanks in advance

**update**

*output for ~/.xsession-errors*

```
Xsession: X session started for root at Wed May 7 17:35:27 MSK 2014
localuser: root being added to access control list
Setting IM through im-switch for locale=all_ALL
Start IM through /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/all_ALL linked to /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/default
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
```

Comment: Can you post your `~/.xsession-errors` file? It sounds like you've removed your default desktop environment. It would also be a good idea to give us the _exact_ commands you ran to "remove and install some software".

Comment: updated my post with an output.
I've used simple deb manager and apt install/remove commands, as well as dpkg -i

Comment: We need to know the _exact_ commands. You have obviously removed something and we can't help you find out what it was unless we know what you actually did. Also, is there any particular reason you are trying to log into the GUI as root? Many/most distributions don't allow that by default. Oh, and if this is a virtual machine, _tell us_.

Comment: ok, just came back from a friend who is sorta specialist on those issues. he said the problem was the following:
somehow by unistalling office (running apt remove libreoffice4.0) I also got lots of other packages removed (including those related to GUI), plus I had some weird logging issue which he said is specific to Ubuntu distribs.

thanks for help everyone

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have deleted your xserver as a dependency to office package?

First, try to make

```
sudo /etc/init.d/[gdm kdm ...] start
```

If nothing happens, look in /var/log for last log messages:

```
ls -lhtr /var/log
```

and read the tail of the latest modified files